# How can I shut down a virtual machine so that I don't incur charges, but do have it shutdown-on-disk as I would do in VMware?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

I have several VMs that are configured and powered off for both operational and DR purposes.

How can I achieve the equivalent of a Azure VM + configuration + resources stored only on (blob) storage and turn it on as needed (with a preferred set of name names, or name variants?

I'm familiar with Azure Automation, but just want to recognize the pieces, and if necessary automation that needs to occur to start/stop this "snapshot" of a base OS VM + lots of customization + software addins.

Comment: As of 2022 Azure does not support yet Hibernation, but there's work in progress. Considerable problem is the disk space needed to store all the memory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/761092/hibernate-azure-vm

Answer (score 0):

well, its kinda hard to figure out what you mean exactly, but your best bet is just creating vms and configuring them automatically or using a golden image. if you choose to use ephemeral OS disk - you are not paying for storage, only for compute, but you cant shut it down (all the changes are lost). Also, ephemeral OS disk might not be supported for custom images.

Apart from that, just deallocating a VM means you are not paying for it - only for the storage.

Comment: Thank you! Once I have a "working POC" of a VM configured as needed, normally in the PC world I would run a "Ghost SigGen" to give the machine a new GUID suitable (sysprep).  Where do I get the step by step directions to prepare a Windows 10 or Server 2019 image for disk? How do I take a running server, and when needed, clone and deploy N instances (using arm, etc)

Comment: I don't know, have you tried googling `azure sysprep` or is it too hard? :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Comment: Seems that this process of asking a question helped me find and clarify what to search for to accomplish a goal. Things look different when coming art problems with a SysOps, vs dev, vs startup, vs cloud/on Prem perspective. LMGTFY was needed in the homogeneity of the Internet past, but don’t think that is broadly sustainable for the future (in dev, ops, or mgmt)  hmm. Interesting thought flow. Thanks 4...